# What payment system to use in a website?

Tags: php, html, css, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a few "ventures" for example

I would like to sell my photos that I have taken, a gallery would be displayed, the photos shown have watermarks on them / less resolution. Then for $0.10 for instance, they can download the copy.

Another one is that I would have people submit sketches of a web design and for $4.95 or something stupid like that, I would take a look at their website, possibly create it and show them a screenshot of the website then they pay the full amount for whatever price.

My point is, I need some sort of way to accept payments but also have it drive a process like give them the photo, or accept and send their scanned photo / photo after payment.

What are some good services for that? What language would that be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends upon how you want to setup this process.

There are many payment providers which support product listing at their end apart from Payment process like BlueSnap, Gate2shop.

And if you do not want to manage and place your photos over there then you can just write a small script which will send photos and related task on the payment completion.

Most of the payment gateway, like Paypal, support a notification URL concept in which all the payment related notifications like payment failed, completion, error etc are send to the mentioned url.

So you can give your script url here and handle all the notifications.

For Paypal integration you can check these links.

https://developer.paypal.com/

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/archive/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Give Stripe a try, it's treated us well - http://stripe.com